Convert Flat JSON to Nested JSON at multiple levels
Below is the JSON I have
[
  {
    "item_attr1": "abc",
    "item_attr2": "123",
    "item_attr3": "123",
    "item_id": "12345",
    "bucket_attr1": 1919,
    "bucket_attr2": "abc",
    "bucket_attr3": 1922,
    "bucket_attr4": "abc",
    "bucket_id_1": "abc",
    "bucket_id_2": "def",
    "bucket_id_3": "ghi",
    "articleattribute1": "abc",
    "articleattribute2": "abc",
    "articleattribute3": "2233",
    "article_id": "123458"
  },
  {
    "item_attr1": "abc",
    "item_attr2": "123",
    "item_attr3": "123",
    "item_id": "543421",
    "bucket_attr1": 1919,
    "bucket_attr2": "abc",
    "bucket_attr3": 1922,
    "bucket_attr4": "abc",
    "bucket_id_1": "abc",
    "bucket_id_2": "mef",
    "articleattribute1": "abc",
    "articleattribute2": "abc",
    "articleattribute3": "2233",
    "article_id": "12345"
  }
]

I need to group by bucket_id_1, bucket_id_2 and bucket_id_3 and then group that result by article_id so that that the output may look like
{
  "buckets": [
    {
      "bucket_id": "abc",
      "bucket_attr1": 1919,
      "bucket_attr2": "abc",
      "bucket_attr3": 1922,
      "bucket_attr4": "abc",
      "articles": [
        {
          "articleattribute1": "abc",
          "articleattribute2": "abc",
          "articleattribute3": "2233",
          "article_id": "12345",
          "items": [
            {
              "item_attr1": "abc",
              "item_attr2": "123",
              "item_attr3": "123",
              "item_id": "543421"
            },
            {
              "item_attr1": "abc",
              "item_attr2": "123",
              "item_attr3": "123",
              "item_id": "XYZ123"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "articleattribute1": "abc",
          "articleattribute2": "abc",
          "articleattribute3": "2233",
          "article_id": "123458",
          "items": [
            {
              "item_attr1": "abc",
              "item_attr2": "123",
              "item_attr3": "123",
              "item_id": "12345"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "bucket_id": "def",
      "bucket_attr1": 1919,
      "bucket_attr2": "abc",
      "bucket_attr3": 1922,
      "bucket_attr4": "abc",
      "articles": [
        {
          "articleattribute1": "abc",
          "articleattribute2": "abc",
          "articleattribute3": "2233",
          "article_id": "12345",
          "items": [
            {
              "articleattribute1": "abc",
              "articleattribute2": "abc",
              "articleattribute3": "2233",
              "article_id": "123458",
              "items": [
                {
                  "item_attr1": "abc",
                  "item_attr2": "123",
                  "item_attr3": "123",
                  "item_id": "12345"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "bucket_id": "ghi",
      "bucket_attr1": 1919,
      "bucket_attr2": "abc",
      "bucket_attr3": 1922,
      "bucket_attr4": "abc",
      "articles": [
        {
          "articleattribute1": "abc",
          "articleattribute2": "abc",
          "articleattribute3": "2233",
          "article_id": "12345",
          "items": [
            {
              "articleattribute1": "abc",
              "articleattribute2": "abc",
              "articleattribute3": "2233",
              "article_id": "123458",
              "items": [
                {
                  "item_attr1": "abc",
                  "item_attr2": "123",
                  "item_attr3": "123",
                  "item_id": "12345"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

I tried to write Jolt transformation and shiftr operations and also used below site for validating my transformation but could not get the result in my expected format

You can use the following transformation :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*_1": "buckets[0].&(0,1)",
        "bucket_attr*": "buckets[0].&",
        "article*": "buckets[0].articles[0].&",
        "item*": {
          "@": "buckets[0].articles[0].items[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {// pick single elements from each array those have identical repeating of them
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE",
          "articles": {
            "*": {
              "*": "ONE"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]

the demo on the site https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :


Hi Ozhan
Thanks for the answer. I made a mistake in explaining transformation properly.
First i want to group by buckets such that multiple articles come under it and then i want to group by articles and items such that multiple items come under it.
Have changes the target JSON. please note that there can more than 2 entries in source JSON which can belong have different bucket ids, article ids and item items.
Item ids are unique. but bucket id and item id can be repeated

Well, in the new case grouping is made by the bucket_ids only from the first object, how can we determinre the logic behind it then.? Secondly, there are three of them within the first object while two of them exist for the second one, why? Btw, what did you try to solve the problem, can you please show it us @ShashiKiranGM

As of now i am only able to group by bucket_id_1.  Below is the Spec I have
[
  { // group by ProposalId values
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@(1,bucket_id_1).&",
        "article_id|articleattribute2|articleattribute3|articleattribute1": {
          "@": "@(2,bucket_id_1).articles[&2].&"
        },
        "item_id|item_attr1|item_attr2|item_attr3": {
          "@": "@(2,bucket_id_1).articles[&2].items[&2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // nest all JSON value within Proposal array
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "OrderPreps[]"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE",
          "articles": "MANY",
          "items": "MANY"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of redundant nulls
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
  }
]

I have two issues to be resolved:

I would like to split entries in source JSON if bucket_id_2 and bucked_id_3 is present and then use bucket_id in place of bucket_id_1, bucket_id_2 and bucket_id_3
For example if Source JSON is like
[
{
"bucket_id_1": "1",
"bucket_id_2": "2",
"bucket_id_3": "3",
// Other key-values
}
]


Then I would like to Split to
[
  {
   "bucket_id": "1"
    //other key-values
  },
  {
   "bucket_id": "2"
    //other key-values
  },
  {
   "bucket_id": "3"
    //other key-values
  }
]

and finally apply my transformation on this list grouping bucket_id.

I am able to insert articles of each bucket into that bucket, but suppose we have item_ids which are different but article_id value is the  same, then we should have one article and inside that two items, but i am getting 2 articles with an item in each of them as follows
{
"OrderPreps" : [ {
"articles" : [ {
"items" : [ {
"item_attr1" : "abc",
"item_attr2" : "123",
"item_attr3" : "123",
"item_id" : "12345"
} ],
"articleattribute1" : "abc",
"articleattribute2" : "abc",
"articleattribute3" : "2233",
"article_id" : "12345"
}, {
"items" : [ {
"item_attr1" : "abc",
"item_attr2" : "123",
"item_attr3" : "123",
"item_id" : "543421"
} ],
"articleattribute1" : "abc",
"articleattribute2" : "abc",
"articleattribute3" : "2233",
"article_id" : "12345"
} ],
"bucket_attr1" : 1919,
"bucket_attr2" : "abc",
"bucket_attr3" : 1922,
"bucket_attr4" : "abc",
"bucket_id_1" : "abc",
"bucket_id_2" : "def",
"bucket_id_3" : "ghi"
} ]
}



It can also happen that bucket_id_1, bucket_id_2 and bucket_id_3 may be present for one entry and in second entry bucket_id_3  could be null

Why not you use a database, insert all those json objects there, run the sql query you need and get the result set back as json array?
